# Why does my anonymous object not have the collection in a unit test, but works fine in the actual application?

Tags: c#, expandoobject

I'm writing up some unit tests for the following code:

```
    public async Task<dynamic> GetResults([FromBody] MultiSelectQueryResultRequest request)
    {
        var results = await _multiSelectRepository.GetResults(request);
        var items = new List<ExpandoObject>();
        foreach (var result in results)
        {
            var expando = new ExpandoObject();
            foreach (var column in request.columns.Split(','))
            {
                AddProperty(expando, column, result.GetType().GetProperty(column).GetValue(result));
            }
            items.Add(expando);
        }
        return new { Items = items };
    }
```

Back in my test I have this:

```
    [Fact]
    public async Task GetResults_ReturnsResults()
    {
        var request = new MultiSelectQueryResultRequest { project_block = "SM2 BLK 3B", APBU_nalc = "cwex", columns = "msl_key,FZBSTR_nalc,SAD_pn" };
        var response = await _controller.GetResults(request);
        Assert.Equal(105, response.Items.Count);
    }
```

Which is failing with this message:

> Message: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException :
>   'object' does not contain a definition for 'Items'

When debugging I can definitely see that Items is inside response and it has 105 elements within it. In my mind it should be passing, obviously it isn't though. Why?

Comment: Anonymous types are internally visible, so once they cross the assembly barrier you can't access their properties anymore.

Comment: @StriplingWarrior oh interesting. So because the test assembly is different it no longer has that property even though I can even see it in the debugger? Is the debugger under some different context? That seems crazy to me :P

Comment: The debugger has full knowledge of the internal state of the entire runtime; the runtime's debugger subsystem does not have to *obey* the rules of data visibility because it *implements* those rules! But the runtime must *enforce* those rules so that you do not abuse them. Anonymous types are internal; we did that deliberately so that you would not attempt to use them across assemblies.

Comment: @rball: It shouldn't be all that surprising: haven't you noticed that the debugger can access private fields?